# Set new size of dynamic array from an external function/class?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, resize

My main code declares a pointer  that needs to be resized from an external function. Ex:

```
double *vect =NULL;
classobj object;

object.func(vect);

//--- print the outcome
for(int j=0; j<4; ++j)
   cout << vect[j] << " .. " << endl;
```

where function func() is part of `classobj` defined in an another file (say `classobj.h` and `.cpp`) as

```
void classobj::func(double *_vect){

  _vect  = new double[4];

  for(int j=0; j<4; ++j)
    _vect[j] = 3.0*j +1 ;

};
```

The problem is that `vect` has not been resized. I get segmentation fault. Any idea please on how to use pointers in this case?

Comment: Declare the function as `void classobj::func(double*& _vect)`. That said, this is horrible design and is destined to cause even more issues down the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a reference to your Array and then you are creating a new Array and assigning it to the pointer in the function. You Need to pass a pointer of the pointer and then reassign the address of that pointer:

```
void classobj::func(double **_vect){
    (*_vect)  = new double[4];
```

Although this solution will work I recommend using a `std::vector` for this purpose and passing it by reference to that function

Comment: Well, if you use std::vector then there's no need of caring about resizing. It's performed automatically as you insert elements in the vector. Thus, you don't have to care about memory management.

Comment: are you sure it should not be  `(*_vect)  = new double[4]`?